# Why ambari ResourceManager HA need restart Zookeeper？

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, ambari

I want to update a yarn cluster which managed by ambari to HA. But I do not want to restart the zookeeper.
Why ambari ResourceManager HA need restart Zookeeper？

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper controls which resource manager is the primary / secondary. The configs of the resource managers change, therefore so do Zookeeper servers behind them